# solve complicated ODE groups using spicy.integrate solve_bvp unsuccessfully

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

When I run my code sentence by sentence, no errors exist. However, when I check out the results of `AA` (bvp solution in my code), it displays that I solve this ODE group falsely.

How can I run this code correctly?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k=0.06
Theta=20
p=0.4 #porosity of the electrode 
pi=3.14
L=4 #cm
R=8.314 
F=96485
t2=0.78
C0=1
T=298.15
vs=1
aa=0.5
ac=0.5
a=23300
i0=2e-2
Dad=0.5
I=2 
Da=900
B=(1/k*(p**(1.5)))+1/Theta
C=I/(2*pi*L*Theta)
D=2*R*T/F
E=Da*p**(1.5)

def battery(r,y):
A=np.exp((aa*F*y[0])/(R*T))-np.exp((-ac*F*y[0])/(R*T))
return np.vstack((y[1]*B-C/r+(D*y[3]/y[2])*(0.22+y[2]),
                  A/((1/a*i0)+A/Dad),
                  y[3],
                  ((1-E)/E)*y[3]+(0.22/(E*F))*(A/((1/a*i0)+A/Dad))))                                       

def boundary(ya,yb):
return [ya[1]-2/(2*3.14*4*10*4.2),yb[1],ya[2]-9,yb[3]]

n = 25
r = np.linspace(4.2, 6.9, n)
y = np.ones((4,r.size))
AA=solve_bvp(battery,boundary,r,y)
```

The results are below:

```
sol: <scipy.interpolate.interpolate.PPoly object at 0x11303f728>
    status: 2
   success: False
```

Comment: It looks like more an issue about the physics (units, equations?) than a problem about the code or the solver... Do you have a simpler version which works?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about mathematics, no programming.

Comment: @xdze2 No, I don't have simpler version. No errors exist before solve these equations, I don't know what's wrong with my code. A question I want to ask you: What's the common errors lead to bad results when using spicy.integrate.solve_bvp?

Comment: First, I would double check all units and order of magnitudes. For example in the expression for A, there is a huge difference between the two terms: `np.exp((aa*F*y[0])/(R*T))~2e9 ` and `np.exp((-ac*F*y[0])/(R*T))~3e-9` if y[0] is assumed to be about 1, same for `(1/a*i0)` vs. `A/Dad`... maybe it is ok, but then the expression could be simplified...